# iOS Extension kJavaScriptFinalizeArgumentKey

Tags: ios8

The iOS 8 Extension SDK allows you to interact with a web pages using JavaScript.

The guide references a `kJavaScriptFinalizeArgumentKey` constant to use as a dictionary key when passing data back to the `finalize()` method in the JS.

Xcode doesn't recognise this, nor the other `kJavaScriptResultsKey` referenced in the docs.

Does anyone know if this is either not yet implemented, or if I need to import a module for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

replace 'kJavaScriptFinalizeArgumentKey' with  'NSExtensionJavaScriptFinalizeArgumentKey'

so the SDK sample should be

```
   NSExtensionItem *extensionItem = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];
   extensionItem.attachments = @[[[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem: @{NSExtensionJavaScriptFinalizeArgumentKey: @{@"bgColor":@"red"}} typeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList]];

   [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[extensionItem]  completionHandler:nil];
```